# index.tsx can't resolve App component in React app. .Tsx extensions are not recognised

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I have just runned create-react-app, moved some code and components from another project and now I cannot figure out why I get an error that it fails to compile. App component exist exactly in the destination where it can't be found. I suppose there is some hint in console, but I cannot figure out what can be the issue.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { App } from "./components/App/App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

[image]

Here I add a picture of App component to show You the location of app component.
Can You please suggest what is wrong here ?

[image]

Here You can see my package.json

```
{
  "name": "flask_react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.5",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.15",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "prettier": "^2.8.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "start-backend": "cd backend && env/bin/flask run --no-debugger",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "eslint": "eslint ./src/**/*.{ts,tsx}"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.64",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@types/react-icons": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.19",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.39.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.39.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.24.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.8",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { App } from "./components/App/App";
```

You are destructuring your App import with the curly brackets, which returns undefined. Instead it should be

```
import App from './components/App/App';
```

**EDIT:** as Yuriy pointed out in the comments, since this isn't a default export then what I said above won't fix the problem. I have thought of something else though, what if you specify the extension? Like so

```
import { App } from "./components/App/App.tsx";
```

Comment: It should not, since App is exported as a const, not a default export.

Comment: You're right, I had overlooked this. Thank you for pointing it out, I've edited my answer.

Comment: when I do as You suggest in the editem comment I'm getting a typescript error that an import path cannot end with .tsx extension. I have tied with default export and it still show same error, like initially.

Comment: I have created another repository and noticed that issue occurs when I intiall typescript package and change index and App files from .js to .tsx extension. For some reason it cannot resovle it, but totally don't have idea why

Comment: @marcinb1986 what bundler do you use? how is your typescript loader configured?

Comment: I used create-react-app, so as I understand ( if I'm not wrong ) it's webpack bundler. I used yarn add create-react-app and then installed different packages separately. Regarding typesctipt loader I used commend yarn add ts-loader. I have edited my post and added package.json, maybe it will help. I see it's and issue with missing tsconfig file which is not generated by create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

according to the error most probably here you are not including the `.tsx` extenstion to your extensions array. update your `webpack.config.js` file as below :

```js
module.exports = {
  // ... 
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
  },
}
```